# PhpStorm don't show /var/www on opening

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, var

I installed PhpStorm on Linux Mint 19.2 . When I try to open the project, the editor doesn't show me the `/var/www` directory. What can I do? I don't have this problem with VSCode

In lamp installation I used: ([LAMP Installation](https://wiredzero.com/lamp))

```
sudo chgrp www-data /var/www
sudo chmod 775 /var/www
sudo chmod g+s /var/www
usermod -a -G www-data username
sudo chown username /var/www/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed PhpStorm with Software Manager so problem was here. After deleting app and installing it with snap and the problem was gone.

```
sudo snap install phpstorm --classic
```